# Navigation bar custom back button

Tags: ios, swift, button, uinavigationbar

I would like to add rounded background color to my custom navigator bar back button:

[image: Back Button]

I have transparent Navigation bar and on some of the screens this button is not visible. But, there are other screens, where Navigation bar becomes visible with background color, and my button on that bar looks like this:

[image: Back button 2]

On other screens, button should have grey background color.

Code I have for button right now is:

```
    let backIconImage = UIImageView()
    backIconImage.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 0.4)
    backIconImage.layer.cornerRadius = backIconImage.frame.height / 2
    backIconImage.image = UIImage(named: "Back")

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backIconImage.image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backIconImage.image
```

But I get only button image without background. 
I my assets I have "Back" button without background and if I change it to an image with background - property **Tint** that is configured from storyboard add white overlay to that button. But without it - buttons becomes of default color.

Here is how I configure my Navigation bar from storyboards:

[image: Navigation Bar Properties]

Would be thankful for any thoughts or code samples on how to make it work. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You dont seem to be using your imageview that contains your backbutton image anywhere.
Also, when setting your cornerRadius, the frame is 0/0 because the view didnt get layouted yet if you would be using it.

Comment: @MartinM For now as test I placed my code for the button inside AppDelegate method - `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` - but no result. As for cornerRadius - what should I do instead?

Comment: Again, you are creating a view that you never use anywhere. In that case it wont make a difference what cornerRadius you set there.

Comment: @MartinM I see. Then how should I use this view with Back button?

Comment: You would probably want to customize navigationItem.backBarButtonItem and use a custom view.